# Output specific line for exiv2?

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, exiv2

Using exiv2, you can output image information in the terminal. However, it outputs several lines of information:

```
exiv2 -ps ~/filelocation/filename.jpg
```

Outputs something like this:

```
File name       : ~/filelocation/filename.jpg
File size       : 12345 Bytes
MIME type       : image/jpeg
Image size      : 800 x 600
~/filelocation/filename.jpg: No Exif data found in the file
```

How do I command the terminal to only output the image size data from this?

What I really want is this:

```
exiv2 -ps ~/filelocation/filename.jpg [some command here]
```

Output:

```
800 x 600
```

Comment: What did you try? Post your efforts along with the question

Comment: exiv2 -ps /filelocation/filename.jpg | grep "Image size" | awk -F ':' '{print $2}'

This gets me close, but I can't figure it out any more than this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this -

```
exiv2 -ps ~/filelocation/filename.jpg |
  sed -n '/Image size/{ s/^.*: //; p; }'
```

sed's `-n` suppresses default output.

`/pattern/` matches line by line.

`{...}` wraps a script of actions to take on lines that match.

`s/^.*: //;` strips the leading string.

`p;` prints the value.

Comment: This made my terminal choke.

Comment: I had to switch to quotation marks:

exiv2 -ps filename.jpg | sed -n "/Image size/{ s/^.*: //; p; }"

Comment: I don't have exiv2, so I flubbed the copy/paste and had a lone backtick. Try now.